# ArcGIS model tries to tabulate the number of rows from multiple table intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, intersection

I'm trying to generate a table that captures the number of rows, and the source feature class, from the intersection of several FCs against one common layer. My expected output is one row per intersection set containing the number of rows intersected and the source feature class for that intersection (technically there are two source feature classes for a given intersection set but the second FC is always the same). However my final table turns out empty and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

My model, as shown, iterates through FCs in a geodatabase and intersects them against a common layer for all FCs. I subsequently use Summary Statistics to get a count of rows, add a field to include the name of the FC selected from the geodatabase, and append this to a dummy table I've generated.

[image]

The process runs and creates a table with the right fields but the cells are empty.[image]

Comment: After the add field don't you want to calculate something into it? Also your model is highly inefficient and may be the root of the problem? Append takes a list as input not a dataset on each iteration. So you need to use the collects value tool after add field, that is all in a sub-model with the master model having just the append tool. Read the help file on sub models.

Comment: @Hornbydd: Thx - I've looked at the help file. Other than to simplify the model I don't really understand why I need a submodel in this case; I don't need a second iterator, do I? I've added Calculate Value and Collect Values after Add Field but this has made my Append more confusing - my schema appears as "1" now.

Comment: You need a sub model as EVERYTHING will run as many times as the iterator loops. Your append tool needs to run ONCE taking a list of input datasets. Your answer to your question is not a good solution and will be considerably slow than the sub model feeding into a single append tool.

Answer (score 1):

The change that was needed is reflected below: I added and calculated the field before appending the information to a table. [image]